# Не выводятся темы с количеством обращений, равным нулю

Tags: sql

```
select distinct 
    /*row_number() over(order by (count(T1.SER_ID))desc) as Row
    ,*/t206.rct_name As [Тема]
    ,count(T1.SER_ID) as 'Кол-во'

from    servicedesk.dbo.ITSM_SERVICECALLS AS T1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN servicedesk.dbo.itsm_ser_cft001  AS T201 ON T201.itsm_ser_cft001_oid = T1.SER_OID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN servicedesk.dbo.REP_CODES AS T202 ON T202.rcd_oid = T201.A3$_CORRECTED_ERROR_OID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN servicedesk.dbo.REP_CODES_TEXT AS T203 ON T203.rct_rcd_oid = T202.rcd_rcd_oid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN servicedesk.dbo.itsm_ser_cft001  AS T204 ON T204.itsm_ser_cft001_oid = T1.SER_OID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN servicedesk.dbo.REP_CODES AS T205 ON T205.rcd_oid = T204.A3$_CORRECTED_ERROR_OID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN servicedesk.dbo.REP_CODES_TEXT AS T206 ON T206.rct_rcd_oid = T205.rcd_oid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN servicedesk.dbo.ITSM_SER_CUSTOM_FIELDS AS T5 ON T5.SCF_SER_OID = T1.SER_OID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN servicedesk.dbo.ITSM_WORKGROUPS AS T79 ON T79.WOG_OID = T1.SER_ASS_WOG_OID

where
    datediff([day],(T5.SCF_SCDATE1 + CAST(4.0 AS DECIMAL)/24),current_timestamp)=0
    and T79.WOG_NAME = 'SBBOL-SD'
    and t203.rct_name is not NULL
    and t206.rct_name not like '%Прочее%'
    and t206.rct_lng_oid = 1033
group by
    t206.rct_name
order by 2 desc
```

Данный скрипт выгружает темы и количество зарегистрированных по ним обращений. Однако темы, у которых количество = 0, не выводит. (

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

На пальцах. Если вы используете LEFT JOIN, то таблица с темами должна быть слева, а COUNT считать по столбцу таблицы справа.

Если хотите, чтобы вам написали решение, упростите запрос, сведя его до демонстрации проблемы.